# send value in text input react native

Tags: reactjs, navigation, state, native, setstate

native,

here I take the value from the first page.

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectPickup:'',
        }
    }

ongNavigationDetail = ()=>{
        let params = {
            pickup : this.state.selectPickup
        }
        console.log(params)
        // send to third page
    }

  render() {
    const  userLocation  = this.props.navigation.getParam('pickup'); // get value from first page
    return (
         <CardItem header>
         {/* <Text style={{ fontSize: 12}}>{userLocation}</Text> */}
         <Input  onChangeText={userLocation => this.setState({selectPickup:userLocation})} value={userLocation}/>
         </CardItem>

    <Button block info style={styles.MainBtn} onPress={this.ongNavigationDetail}>
      <Text style={styles.btnText}>Next</Text>
    </Button>
    )}
```

on the second page, here I take the value **userLocation** to send a third trip but when I console the value is undifined, where is the explosion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currently, your navigation object doesn't have access to `getParams` function. Maybe you can access it simply like this.

```
 this.pros.navigation.route.params
```

Comment: here i am using react navigation 4, the data has appeared,
I asked how to use userLocation to send it to the third page